# LDAP authenticating partially. Password being replaced

Tags: linux, authentication, ldap, openldap, pam

After a week of struggling to find out why some of our machines are Authenticating off of our LDAP servers and some are not I noticed that after PAM binds to see if the uid exists it then sends the users password. At the packet level, I can see that when I auth on the machines that are working that I see my password come through. When I auth on a machine that is not authing I see the packet at the server with the password as "INCORRECT". What could possibly be changing that? I've searched the pam_ldap, nss_ldap and pam source but to no avail. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you will have to change your nsswitch.conf file aswell:

method A:

## /etc/nsswitch.conf

passwd: files ldap

versus:

## /etc/nsswitch.conf

passwd: ldap files

Which would theoretically reverse the order